# SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'user_id' cannot be null in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, vue.js

I create a todo app in laravel with vue. I have two tables: users and todos; every user has many todos like this:
User.php model:

```
class User extends Authenticatable {
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];
    public function todos()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(
            Todos::class,
            'user_id',
            'user_id'
        );
    }
}
```

Todos.php model:

```
class Todos extends Model
{
    //
    protected $fillable = ['title', 'completed', 'user_id'];

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
```

then I defined this route:

```
Route::post('/v1/todo', 'todosController@addTodo');
```

this is my addTodo from todosController:

```
 public function addTodo(Request $request)
    {
        $uid = Auth::user()->id;
        //dd($uid);

        $todoCreated = new Todos([
            'title' => $request->input('title'),
            'completed' => 0
        ]);
        $user = User::find($uid);
        //dd($user);

        //dd($todoCreated);
        dd($user->todos()->create([
            'title' => $request->input('title'),
            'completed' => 0,
        ]));
}
```

when I send form data it shows me this error:`Illuminate\Database\QueryException SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'user_id' cannot be null (SQL: insert into` todos `(`title`,` completed`,` user_id`,` updated_at`,` created_at`) values (darya, 0, ?, 2020-07-06 12:17:45, 2020-07-06 12:17:45))`.
I am new in laravel and I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've passed wrong param in relationship.

```
public function todos()
{
    return $this->hasMany(
        Todos::class,'user_id','id'
    );
}


return $this->hasMany(Todos::class, 'foreign_key', 'local_key');
```